# lexsort zeros before negatives?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have some data that I want to sort, but this method using numpy.lexsort()

```
data = np.zeros(shape=(n,6))
# some routine that partially populates the table
index = np.lexsort((data[:,0],data[:,1]))
data = data[index] # sort
```

used on a table such as

```
-500    0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
-400    0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

returns data such as:

```
0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0     0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
-500    0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
-400    0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

but that's weird, right?

Comment: The last column is the primary key, so it gets sorted correctly of course. You have to change your order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seburg noted, what you're seeing is not incorrect. Lexsort sorts by the last key provided, then the second-to-last, and so on, which might seem a bit backward. From the docstring:

> The last key in the sequence is used
>   for the primary sort order, the second-to-last key for the secondary sort
>   order, and so on. The keys argument must be a sequence of objects that
>   can be converted to arrays of the same shape. If a 2D array is provided
>   for the keys argument, it's rows are interpreted as the sorting keys and
>   sorting is according to the last row, second last row etc.

What you're seeing is correctly sorted given this, but what you probably wanted to do was the following:

```
data = np.zeros(shape=(n,6))
# some routine that partially populates the table
index = np.lexsort((data[:,1],data[:,0]))
data = data[index] # sort
```